# Craft CMS . Service unavailable

Tags: error-message

I am trying to install Craft CMS on Ubuntu 14.04 running NGINX, I get this error log, any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
2017/08/26 16:18:08 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.503] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /usr/share/nginx/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:800
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/nginx/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(203): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /usr/share/nginx/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(185): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /usr/share/nginx/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php(19): require_once('/usr/share/ngin...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/
```

Thanks

Comment: 503 means "service unavailable."  Since PHP seems to be available, make sure MySQL is running.

Answer (score 4):

The 503 error that is triggered from that log entry happens when Craft files are in place on the server, but it haven't been installed yet and someone loads the front-end of the website.

Assuming you've set everything else up correct, you just need to complete step #5 in the install docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/installing#step-5-run-the-installer

Comment: this even applies to craft v3, thanks Brad!